# Como usar 'use' en Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Estoy aprendiendo Laravel, y en un proyecto he visto que dentro de un controlador no ponen la ruta completa en el use y la acortan.

```
use Auth;
use Validator;
use App\User;
```

¿Porque funciona esto?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No pones la ruta completa si la clase está en el mismo namespace. Para los controladores generalmente el namespace es `App\Http\Controllers`.

Entonces para tu ejemplo, `Auth` y `Validator` tendrían que esta en el mismo namespace que el controlador donde los estás usando (`App\Http\Controllers`) para que funcionen. 
Pero no es el caso, pues Auth y Validator, son clases de `Illuminate\Support\Facades`, entonces deben tener definido un alias en `config/app.php` para no tener que poner todo el namespace, algo así `'Auth' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth::class,` y lo mismo para `Validator`.
Puedes ver en `config/app.php` dentro del array `aliases` si están ahí.

En cambio `User`, que seguramente es un modelo, tiene otro namespace. Entonces pones el namespace y la clase: `App\User`.

Comment: [Este](https://github.com/codebriefly/VUEJS_LARAVEL_JWT_AUTH/blob/master/app/Http/Controllers/AuthController.php) proyecto no tiene esos controladores y aun asi funciona

Comment: No conozco el proyecto, y tendría que estudiarlo para ver como funciona. Pero `Auth` por ejemplo, debe tener definido un alias en `config/app.php` para no tener que poner todo el namespace, algo así `'Auth' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth::class,`. Lo mismo para `Validator`. Puedes ver en `config/app.php` dentro del array `aliases` si están ahí.

Comment: Vale, ya lo he entendido, muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Son el namespace donde se encuentran ubicadas las clases que requieres

Por ejemplo `App\User` indica el *namespace* principal es `App` el cual apunta a la carpeta `app` y dentro busca un modelo llamado `User` cuya clase se llama del mismo modo

Esto no es solo tema de Laravel sino que en PHP se puede hacer con la implementación de PSR-4, para la carga automática de clases evitas el uso de `requiere` o funciones similares

Por ejemplo al hacer uso de use `App\User` tendrás la clase `User` importada y por lo tanto acceso a sus métodos y propiedades

Si revisas cada `namespace` hace referencia a la ruta de carpetas dentro de la cual está el recurso al que deseamos llegar

Entonces las clases `Auth` y `Validator` existen dentro de la carpeta `Controllers` por eso solo hace la importación de las mismas por su nombre pues existen al mismo nivel que el controlador que las usa